# specific fb page will not work with like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I've had this like button/box setup for this specific page for some time.  But now it;s stopped working:

Using code generated (for iframe) on this page:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

to display this fb page:

http://www.facebook.com/JohnPurkiss

does not display/work.  If I amend the like button url in the iframe to another fb page, it does work.  I'm not tryinig to use a button/plugin that requires an app.  Just a plain 'ol simple button.  But it appears to me there is an issue with this specific fb page (johnpurkiss one above)

Any advice/help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the "page" you linked to is in actual fact a personal user.

You can not "like" a user in the same way that

- you can not add a page as a friend...
- or "poke" an event...
- or subscribe to a photo...

You'll gave to provide an actual **page** to be liked.

As you can see from the screenshot below taken from the link you provided, there is no like button to be found.

Only an "Add Friend" and "Subscribe" button.  I'm not sure if converting your profile into a page is the way you want to go, but it is possible.  [You can learn how at this link](https://www.facebook.com/help?page=213602951994043).